# How to pass value to another class

Tags: java, android, http

In my android project I have **pm.class**, where,

```
try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String ct = till.toString(entity);
            Log.d("The error", TAG + " response: " + ct);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 201) {

                Pickerror error = new Gson().fromJson(content,
    Pickerror.class);
Log.e("Error1",TAG + "  Error is ["+ tf.getMyname() + "], field["
                                + error.getFill() + "], fullmessage: "
                                + error.getMessage());



                throw new Exception("Error is[" + error.getField()
                        + "] - " + error.getMessage());
            }


            return new Gson().fromJson(content, mat.class);

        } catch (IOException ese) {

            Log.e("error2",
                    TAG + " exception error: "
                            + ese.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

the above code is for connect to the server..

And I also have **mainActivity.class**, where I have code:--

```
 protected Intent doInBackground(String... params) {


                    String tk = null;
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    try {
                        tk = pmm.us(name,partner);

                        data.putString(tk, name);
                        data.putString(tk2,partner);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

///here I want to show

                    }

                    final Intent re = new Intent();
                    re.putExtras(data);
                    return re;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
                    if(?????????){

//I want to show the error
                    } else {
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        }
```

I want to show the pm.class error(that is showing in the Log.e()) to the  catch section of the **MainActivity.class**..How Can I do that?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  How do these objects relate to one another?  What are the object instances you're using, and what operations are you trying to invoke on those objects?

Comment: Well, as David said, it is not 100% clear what you are trying to accomplish. But from my POV I would change the declaration of the method you want the exception from (in your pm.class (note: class-names should start with upper case letters in Java)) to "throws IOException". Then you must remove the catch clause and can add a try/catch clause in your mainActivity.

Comment: Make sure your network task runs in the background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your MainActiviy.Class**

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url_parameter_key", name));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url_parameter_key", partner));

new NetworkRequest(new CallbackInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onRequestSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonObject,toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }, params).execute();
```

**your pm.class**

```
public class NetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

public interface CallbackInterface {

    public void onRequestSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject);

}

String rootUrl="your url";
private CallbackInterface callback;


public NetworkRequest(CallbackInterface callbackInterface,
        List<BasicNameValuePair> params,
        ) {
    this.callback = callbackInterface;
    this.rootUrl =rootUrl + "/?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return networkRequet();
}

private JSONObject networkRequet() {
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(rootUrl);
        Log.i("url", rootUrl);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        if (httpGet != null) {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            Log.i("Result", result);
        }
        return new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        error = ErrorType.JSONPARSER_ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        error = ErrorType.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        error = ErrorType.IO_ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        callback.onRequestSuccess(result);
}
```